# Get properties of qStylesheet

Tags: c++, qt

For my aplication I use qStylesheet. In a custom widget I draw some things overriding the paintevent method. I want to use the colors of this widget, set by the qStylesheet to achieve consistency, and later on configurability. How can I get the properties set by the qStylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get QPalette and get current properties. For example:

```
widget.palette().brush().color();
```

Another way is to get stylesheet and parse it (maybe with regular expressions), but I think it is not the best approach.